# Boostrap affix only when past scroll point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement Bootstraps Affix function on my site, the sidebar I would like to only scroll after the adjacent div starts going out of view.

I would like the `.submenu` to only be sticky once the first `.test-div` starts to scroll out of view, so it scrolls with `.test-div` initially to the top but once the first `.test-div` starts to go out of sight should it become sticky.

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/epnfzo4s/)

CSS:

```
body {
    padding-top: 200px;
}
.test-div {
    min-height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.footer {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 500px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">

            <div id="1" class="test-div">
                <h2>Header</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="2" class="test-div">
                <h2>Header</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="3" class="test-div">
                <h2>Header</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="4" class="test-div">
                <h2>Header</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="5" class="test-div">
                <h2>Header</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="6" class="test-div">
                <h2>Header</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="7" class="test-div">
                <h2>Header</h2>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="400" class="submenu">
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) it says you need to provide CSS for the positioning and width of your affixed content. Also for bottom offset you need to add CSS for class `.affix-bottom`.

> **Usage**
>
> Use the affix plugin via data attributes or manually with your own
>   JavaScript. In both situations, you must provide CSS for the
>   positioning and width of your affixed content.

**CSS**

```
.affix{ top: 0px;}
.affix-bottom{ position: absolute;}
```

Since you wanted the sidebar to stick only after first test-div is going out of view, you have to consider the height of the first div along with the body padding-top for `data-offset-top` and same way for the `data-offset-bottom` consider the height of the footer.

```
<div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="600" data-offset-bottom="400">
    sub menu will go here<br/>
    sub menu will go here<br/>
    ....
</div>
```

Update:

You can set the `data-offset` attributes dynamically by using getting the top value of the second `test-div` using [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

```
var pos = $('.test-div').eq(0).offset();
var pos_foot = $('.footer').height();

$('[data-spy="affix"]').attr("data-offset-top",pos.top);
$('[data-spy="affix"]').attr("data-offset-bottom",pos_foot);
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/epnfzo4s/8/)

Comment: Is there a way I could dynamically set the `data-offset-top` using say jQuery? So it should see where on the screen the first `test-div` finishes and use that position as the offset.

Comment: @Imran Yes, you can set the values dynamically. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry my description was not accurate, how can the `pos` variable be changed so that as soon as any part of the first `.test-div` is out of view the sidebar becomes sticky? I attempted `var pos = $('.test-div').eq(1).offset() - $('.test-div').eq(1).height();` but this did not work.

Comment: Oh then you need offest of the first test-div. `$(".test-div").eq(0)` [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/epnfzo4s/8/)

Answer (score 2):

You should add css for your affixed submenu.

This will be applied while affixing after it reaches top-offset.

```
.affix{
 top:0px;
}
```

The following will be applied after it reaches the bottom offset.

```
.affix-bottom{
 position:absolute;
}
```

The best practice would be to determine the offset beforehand instead of setting it via javascript. - *Just a suggestion.*

Here is my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/clickdilip/epnfzo4s/7/

Answer (score -2):

Did you test this without the top 200px padding on the body? Because that also counts when JS calculates offset-top. Or simply give it a higher offset-top.

Comment: The padding on the body was just to simulate the extra spacing on my real page which has elements like the header above the content and sidebar.